# What is the greatest $b<1000$ for which 2015 is a member of a sequence $s_n$

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, recurrence-relations

Given a sequence of integers:
$s_1=3, s_2=b$ and $s_{n+2}=s_{n+1}+(-1)^ns_n$

What is the greatest value of $b<1000$ for which the number 2015 is a member of the sequence? Justify your answer.

So far what I've done is list out as many members as possible but this problem is unique because I cannot see a pattern. Please help thanks!!

Comment: I am not really sure, but perhaps you could use the $\gcd$ concept to try to obtain some results in this direction.

Answer (score 1):

Let's see. So, each odd term is the difference of two previous terms, and each even term is the sum thereof.
$$\begin{array}{|c|c|}
\hline
n& s(n) \\ \hline
1& a \\ \hline
2& b \\ \hline
3& b-a \\ \hline
4& 2b-a \\ \hline
5& b \\ \hline
6& 3b-a \\ \hline
7& 2b-a \\ \hline
8& 5b-2a \\ \hline
9& 3b-a \\ \hline
10& 8b-3a \\ \hline
11& 5b-2a \\ \hline
12& 13b-5a \\ \hline
13& 8b-3a \\ \hline
\end{array} $$
Rings a bell?

Looks like $s_{2k}=s_{2k+3}=F_{k+1}\cdot b-F_{k-1}\cdot a$. (I may be off by 1 in either direction, and in any case this is for you to prove.) Also, your $a=3$.

See where this gets you.

Answer (score 0):

Start the sequence $3,b,b-3,2b-3,...$
$b$ can't be 2015 because $2015\geq1000$.
$b-3$ can't be 2015 for the same reason.
Then try $2b-3$, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

You have:

$\begin{align}
s_{n + 2}
  &= s_{n + 1} + (-1)^n s_n
\end{align}$

Define the generating function $S(z) = \sum_{n \ge 0} s_n z^n$, multiply the recurrence by $z^n$, sum over $n \ge 0$ and recognize some sums:

$\begin{align}
\frac{S(z) - s_0 - s_1 z}{z^2}
  &= \frac{S(z) - s_0}{z}
      + \sum_{n \ge 0} (-1)^n s_n z^n \\
  &= \frac{S(z) - s_0}{z}
      + \sum_{n \ge 0} s_{2 n} z^{2 n}
      - \sum_{n \ge 0} s_{2 n + 1} z^{2 n + 1}
\end{align}$

Note that:

$\begin{align}
\sum_{n \ge 0} s_{2 n} z^{2 n}
  &= \frac{S(z) + S(-z)}{2} \\
\sum_{n \ge 0} s_{2 n + 1} z^{2 n + 1}
  &= \frac{S(z) - S(-z)}{2}
\end{align}$

This gives:

$\begin{align}
\frac{S(z) - s_0 - s_1 z}{z^2}
  &= \frac{S(z) - s_0}{z}
       + S(-z) \\
S(-z)
  &= \frac{S(z) - s_0 - s_1 z}{z^2} - \frac{S(z) - s_0}{z} \\
S(z)
  &= \frac{S(-z) - s_0 + s_1 z}{z^2} + \frac{S(-z) - s_0}{z}
\end{align}$

Substituting the expression for $S(-z)$ in the last one and solving for $S(z)$:

$\begin{align}
S(z)
  = \frac{s_0 + s_1 z + s_1 z^2 + (s_0 + s_1) z^3}{1 - z^2 - z^4}
\end{align}$

Run the recurrence backwards to get $s_0 = b - 3$, so:

$\begin{align}
S(z)
  = \frac{(b - 3) + b z + b z^2 + b z^3}{1 - z^2 - z^4}
\end{align}$

The generating function for the Fibonacci numbers $F_n$, defined by:

$$
F_{n + 2} = F_{n + 1} + F_n \qquad F_0 = 0, F_1 = 1
$$

is:

$$F(z) = \sum_{n \ge 0} F_n z^n = \frac{z}{1 - z- z^2}$$

For Fibonacci numbers shifted by one:

$$\sum_{n \ge 0} F_{n + 1} z^n = \frac{1}{1 - z - z^2}$$

so our mystery generating function is:

$\begin{align}
S(z)
  &= ((b - 3) + b z + b z^2 + b z^3) \sum_{n \ge 0} F_{n + 1} z^2 \\
[z^{2 n}] S(z)
  &= (b - 3) F_{n + 1} + b F_{n - 1} \\
[z^{2 n + 1}] S(z)
  &= b F_{n + 1} + b F_{n - 1}
\end{align}$

Need to find which one satisfies this. For $n = 1$ the second option gives:

$$2015 = 2015 (F_2 + F_0)$$

while the first one gives for $n = 4$:

$$2015 = (290 - 3) F_5 + 290 F_3$$

so it looks like the largest value is $b = 290$ (checked up to $n = 18$).